# Телефон не принимает Push отправленный с сервера

Tags: php, fcm

Есть рабочий токен FCM. Сразу отмечу что приложение Android принимает Push-уведомления. Я через Firebase Console отправляла тестовое сообщение на определенный токен и Push приходило на телефон.

Но когда я делаю тоже самое с сервера, то получаю успех, но на телефон уведомление не приходит

> {"multicast_id":3472634709388262553,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1592842008684812%d38ad790f9fd7ecd"}]}

Код PHP:

```
<?php

// API access key from Google API's Console
define('API_ACCESS_KEY', '**API KEY**');


$registrationIds = array('**TOKEN**');

// prep the bundle
$msg = array(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: на этот же токен?

Comment: Странно, но код не вполне соответствует примерам из [документации](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Comment: @teran, да токен тот-же. Не обрезан и не изменен